# Convert 2d string array to splitted numeric array using map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
var array=[
    ['0000'],
    ['0000']
]
```

and I'd like to get a result like this:

```
var result=[
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]
]
```

How is this possible with **javascript map**?

My solution with a stupid for loop looks like this:

```js
var array=[
    ['0000'],
    ['0000']
]

var new_array=[]

for (var i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
  new_array.push((array[i].toString().split('').map(Number)))
}
console.log(new_array)
```

> Edit 1.0 How to get the same result if my array looks like this:

```
['0000','0000','0000']
```

> Edit 2.0 Ok last edit - How to turn around the process?
>   So getting from
>  `[[0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]` -- > `[['0000'], ['0000']]`

> EDIT 3 -- OK found the solution for Edit 2 on my own:

```
array.map(a => [a.join('')])
```

Thanks for your help.

Jonas

Comment: Something like this: `var new_array = array.map(x => x[0].split("").map(Number))`?

Comment: What is issue with using `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this. Give the logic with the current item as a function into the `map` function.

```js
var array = [
    ['0000'],
    ['0000']
];

var mappedArray = array.map(item => item[0].split('').map(item => parseInt(item)));

console.log(mappedArray);
```

**Edit 1.0**

```js
var array = [
    '0000',
    '0000'
];

var mappedArray = array.map(item => item.split('').map(item => parseInt(item)));

console.log(mappedArray);
```

**Edit 2.0**

```js
var array = [
    [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]
];

var mappedArray = array.map(item => [item.join('')]);

console.log(mappedArray);
```

Comment: @Jonas0000 In this answer, the `.map(item => parseInt(item))` accomplishes the same thing, although it could be shortened to just `.map(parseInt)`.

Comment: I have used another way :D

Comment: @CRice. Sure thats not the problem. He already edited his post a few seconds ago because in the first version of the answer he forget to add the parseInt function.

Comment: Thanks for your help but please look at my edit above. Greetings

Comment: You need just to remove the `[0]` part from the above code

Comment: Sound legit. Thanks a lot. BTW if your like to help me one more time, theres another edit (I hope the last :p) above. Greetings

Answer (score 1):

> To handle the following scenario...

```
var arrays=[
  ['0000', '0000', '0000'],
  ['0000', '0000', '0000'],
  ['0000', '0000', '0000'],
  // etc...
];

arrays.map(ary => ary.reduce((ary, stg) => ary.concat(stg.split('').map(Number)), []));
// => [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0, etc...], etc...];
```

> A little shorter based on answer from @Josh from Qaribou

```
arrays.map(ary => ary.reduce((ary, stg) => ary.concat(Array.from(stg, Number)), []));
```

Comment: Also the reduce function looks nice. Thanks for your help. Btw if you like to help me again look at my edit above. :)

Comment: Would the reverse require ['0000', '0000'] to this [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] and back to original? Or just back to a string like ['00000000'];

Answer (score 0):

Trivially short after your edit:

```
const array = ['0000', '0000'];
const new_array = array.map(str => Array.from(str, Number));

// [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

Pre-edit:

```
const array = [['0000'], ['0000']];
const new_array = array.map(([str]) => Array.from(str, Number))
```

Gets a bit more verbose if you need to be [['0000', '0000'], ['0000', '0000']] is also valid:

```
const array = [['0123','4567'],['8901','2345']];
const new_array = array.map(strs => strs.reduce((a, e) => (a + e), '')).map(str => Array.from(str, Number));
```